# Reactor : How to convert a Flux of entities into a Flux of DTO objects

Tags: java, reactive-programming, dto, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a User entity and a Role entity.  The fields are not important other than the fact that the User entity has a role_id field that corresponds to the id of its respective role.  Since Spring Data R2DBC doesn't do any form of relations between entities, I am turning to the DTO approach.  I am very new to R2DBC and reactive programming as a whole and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert the `Flux<User>` my repository's findAll() method is returning me to a `Flux<UserDto>`.  My UserDto class is extremely simple :

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDto 
{
    private final User user;

    private final Role role;
}
```

Here is the UserMapper class I'm trying to make :

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserMapper 
{
    private final RoleRepository roleRepo;

    public Flux<UserDto> map(Flux<User> users)
    {
        //???
    }
}
```

How can I get this mapper to convert a `Flux<User>` into a `Flux<UserDto>` containing the user's respective role?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your `RoleRepository` has a `findById()` method or similar to find a `Role` given its ID, and your user object has a `getRoleId()`, you can just do it via a standard map call:

```
return users.map(u -> new UserDto(u, roleRepo.findById(u.getRoleId())));
```

Or in the case where `findById()` returns a `Mono`:

```
return users.flatMap(u -> roleRepo.findById(u.getRoleId()).map(r -> new UserDto(u, r)));
```

You may of course want to add additional checks if it's possible that `getRoleId()` could return null.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  My head is spinning, I AM using R2DBC and Webflux.  My goal is to practice making a REST API that is fully reactive.  Is there a way for your solution to become fully reactive?

Comment: And also, I am using reactive repositories so the findById() method of the RoleRepository returns a Mono<Role> and not a Role, therefore i cannot construct a UserDto object that way.

Comment: @Martin Just takes a `flatMap()` call with another level of mapping instead - see my updated answer. If you're using R2DBC then ignore my comments about using the bounded elastic scheduler.

Comment: MAN this reactive stuff is complex!  I'm hoping building this project will help me grasp the concepts.  Thank god stackoverflow exists LOL.  Cheers!

Comment: @Martin It's a different way of thinking, but when you've got a few different examples and use cases down you'll find it comes quite naturally. It also helps to enforce immutability / cut down on side effects; personally I find it a more resilient way of coding than using standard POJOs.

Comment: I don't understand why you said i wasn't using R2DBC, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Martin I just didn't read it properly :-) When you said "Since Spring Data R2DBC doesn't do any form of relations between entities, I am turning to the DTO approach", I incorrectly assumed by the "DTO" approach you meant you were using standard JPA / Hibernate.

Comment: I have used JPA and Hibernate to hell and back.  I think that's why it's so hard to grasp the reactive concepts.  Practice makes perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Converting the data from business object to database object :

```
private static UserDAO covertUserBOToBUserDAO(UserBO userBO){
    return new UserDAO(userBO.getUserId(), userBO.getName(), userBO.getMobileNumber(), 
     userBO.getEmailId(), userBO.getPassword());
}
```

Converting the data from database object to business object :

```
private static Mono<UserBO> covertUserDAOToBUserBO(UserDAO userDAO){
    return Mono.just(new UserBO(userDAO.getUserId(), userDAO.getName(), 
     userDAO.getMobileNumber(), userDAO.getEmailId(), userDAO.getPassword()));
}
```

Now in service (getAllUsers) asynchronously:

```
public Flux<UserBO> getAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll().flatMap(UserService::covertUserDAOToBUserBO);
}
```

**Since flatMap is asynchronous so we get the benefit from asynchronous operation for even converting the object from DAO to BO.**

Similarly if saving data then I tried below :

```
public Mono<UserBO> saveUser(UserBO userBO)
{
        return 
 userRepository.save(covertUserBOToBUserDAO(userBO)).flatMap(UserService::covertUserDAOToBUserBO);
}
```